# Meteor retrieving sub-array data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This appears to be a fairly regularly asked question. However it is not returning an official answer (or my vocabulary is just so off I can't find it) or I'm not getting suggested the answers to work.

This is a basic iterate through a sub-array of a MongoDB record, the record I am currently playing around with a collection called questions with a single record:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"), 
    "question" : "question 1", 
    "answers" : { 
        "answer1" : "answer 1", 
        "answer2" : "answer 2" 
    } 
}
```

My helper is as below:

```
Template.testquiz.helpers({
    questions: function() {
       return questions.find({});
    },
});
```

Then we have the money shot:

```
<template name="testquiz">
    {{#each questions}}
        {{question}}
        <br /><br />
        {{#each answers}}
            {{this}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

I can get the question to appear, but all variations of how I've attempted to run the nested each over the object "answers" results in an error: this.answers, answers this, questions.answers, pulling the nested each into it's own template and calling that, etc. continuing for an hour. My hunch is that this is standard functionality where I have overlooked some grain of truth from the beginning.

Answers are always appreciated, but if this is a no brainer just point me towards the documents and I'll look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an array there, you have a sub-object. Object's are not *iterable* unless you make a helper to do that.

You should change:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"), 
    "question" : "question 1", 
    "answers" : { 
        "answer1" : "answer 1", 
        "answer2" : "answer 2" 
    } 
}
```

to:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"), 
    "question" : "question 1", 
    "answers" : [ 
        "answer 1", 
        "answer 2" 
    ] 
}
```

Then your template will work.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I'll go and read up on the difference. Thanks for the answer.